# Filtering posts by an already registered taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

register_taxonomy_for_object_type() allows you to "Add an already registered taxonomy to an object type.". I'd like to use The Events Calendar taxonomy as an additional taxonomy for posts, like this

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'tribe_events_cat', 'post' );
```

Why? So they terms for each remain in sync (if a term is added to Events, it's also available to posts).

This works but there doesn't appear to be any way to filter posts by this taxonomy. For instance /?tribe_events_cat=x doesn't filter posts (even after flushing permalinks).

Any ideas? Or alternative suggestions for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The default Event Calendar's query will ask only for 'event' post type.

You need to hook into `pre_get_posts` WordPress action, filter proper query and add 'post' post type to query params. This is the "WordPress way" of doing it.

However, you can try doing it the "Events Calendar way", by searching the codebase for a proper hook (I wasn't able to find them in the documentation). For example, a quick look gave me this:

`tribe_post_types` [filter](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/the-events-calendar/tags/4.4.5/common/src/Tribe/Main.php#L372)

You can try if it works or try searching through the codebase for `do_action` and `apply_filter` calls to find a better hook.

Comment: I may not have explained myself very well. The events category URL is `/events/category/california/`. I'm using `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` to reuse these categories so I don't need duplicate State data. I hope to use a url like `/posts/state/california/`  

`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` allows posts to be associated with State taxonomy but doesn't allow filtering by these. So when I do `/?post_type=post&tribe_events_cat=california` I don't get posts tagged 'california' but instead am redirected to `/events/category/california/`. 

Can you see what I'm trying to do here?